# Odd behavior using d3.extent() in Java Nashorn

Tags: javascript, java, d3.js, nashorn

I implemented a Java library to export SVG files generated with d3.js using the Java 8 embedded scripting interpreter Nashorn. I noticed that the d3.extent() function was not returning appropriate min/max values. For some reason the comparison operators are not working correctly inside a closure.

I called extent in the typical way:

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain(extent(data, function(d) { return d.time; }));
```

I added some logging to the extent function to check the comparisons:

```
var extent = function(array, f) {
  var i = -1,
  n = array.length,
  a,
  b,
  c;

  if (f == null) {
    while (++i < n) if ((b = array[i]) != null && b >= b) { a = c = b; break; }
    while (++i < n) if ((b = array[i]) != null) {
      if (a > b) a = b;
      if (c < b) c = b;
    }
  }

  else {
    while (++i < n) if ((b = f(array[i], i, array)) != null && b >= b) { a = c = b; break; }
    while (++i < n) if ((b = f(array[i], i, array)) != null) {
      console.log(a + " > " + b + " = " + (a > b));
      console.log(c + " < " + b + " = " + (c < b));
      if (a > b) {
        console.log("a > b");
        a = b;
      }
      if (c < b) {
        console.log("c < b");
        c = b;
      }
    }
  }

  return [a, c];
}
```

Here's the output from Nashorn and the JavaScript console in Firefox:

```
Nashorn:
-5.553 > 0 = false
-5.553 < 0 = true
c < b
-5.553 > 7.427 = false
0 < 7.427 = true
c < b
-5.553 > 17.6809 = false
7.427 < 17.6809 = false
-5.553 > 26.5069 = false
7.427 < 26.5069 = false
-5.553 > 33.9389 = false
7.427 < 33.9389 = false
-5.553 > 40.325 = false
7.427 < 40.325 = false

JS Console:
-5.553 > 0 = false
-5.553 < 0 = true
c < b
-5.553 > 7.427 = false
0 < 7.427 = true
c < b
-5.553 > 17.6809 = false
7.427 < 17.6809 = true
c < b
-5.553 > 26.5069 = false
17.6809 < 26.5069 = true
c < b
-5.553 > 33.9389 = false
26.5069 < 33.9389 = true
c < b
-5.553 > 40.325 = false
33.9389 < 40.325 = true
c < b
```

As you can see the Nashorn interpreter is very confused about numerical order. I have a feeling that Nashorn has some slightly different scoping behavior which may be caused by lack of support for the latest JavaScript spec.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem. After the first `b = f(array[i], i, array)` call b becomes an object which can't be compared quite the same as a number. Casting `d.time` to a `Number` fixed the issue. My inexperience with JavaScript typing is showing.

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return Number(d.time); }));
```

Comment: That doesn't really matter. I mean, if given the same input, the two engines should produce the same output, right?